# How to find which php file is running in php-fpm?

Tags: php, fpm

I found a high CPU loading in php-fpm from the top command.  Is there any way to find which file is currently running by php-fpm?

Comment: file or process?

Comment: The php file that the php-fpm is running.

Comment: Try running `php -aux | grep php-fpm` this will list all the process

Comment: Do you mean 'ps -aux | grep php-fpm' ?

Comment: yes my bad not php it is ps

Comment: I can only see this result.  No php filename is listed.

Comment: www-data  3560  0.0  0.1 530256 11016 ?        S    Feb22   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
www-data  3563  0.0  0.1 530256 11016 ?        S    Feb22   0:00 php-fpm: pool www

Answer (score 0):

you can activate php-fpm status page by set `pm.status_path = /status` in php-fpm pool configuration. and serve that page with apache or nginx.

you just have to access http://statuspage/status?full, then you will see php running script like this.

[image]

if you using nginx, you can follow [this tutorial](https://www.tecmint.com/enable-monitor-php-fpm-status-in-nginx/).